# Pygame.Surface driving me crazy

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, pygame-surface

I can get all my images to come up if I only do image.load('').convert_alpha().
When i try getting alittle more control, Surface just kills me, I dont know what to do any more. I need help, please!!

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

white = ((250,250,250))
black = ((0,0,0))

w = 800
h = 600

moveX = 0
moveY = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
pygame.display.set_caption('Paws')

background = pygame.image.load('C:/PythonImg/10121.jpg').convert()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()



Phil = pygame.image.load('C:/PythonImg/Phil_blob.png').convert_alpha()
Philpos = pygame.rect.Rect(0, 0, 400,300)
def Phil((Philpos), Phil):
    screen.blit(Phil, (Philpos))




while pygame.display.get_init():
    pygame.event.pump()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           pygame.display.get_init() == False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                moveX = -10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                moveX = 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                moveY = -10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                moveY = 10
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            moveX = 0
            moveY = 0


    Philpos.move_ip(moveX, moveY)
    Philpos.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())



    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    Phil(Philpos, Phil)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(30)

pygame.QUIT()
quit()
```

Hears my latest error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Paws.py", line 57, in <module>
    Phil(Philpos, Phil)
  File "C:\Python27\Paws.py", line 28, in Phil
    screen.blit(Phil, (Philpos))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store your Surface in a variable called Phil, then you create a function with the same name.

Don't do this. Give your function another name or just remove it.

Comment: Thank you! this has been killing for some time.